# Overriding styles, need to solve only by jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have some simple kind of voting mechanic, all magic staff provides via jQuery, but it's working fine now only because I have `!important` declaration in CSS: `.rating-hover { background-color: yellow !important; }`. How to remove this declaration & solve this only by jQuery?

So problem is how to always show yellow background-color on hover, even if we select some items with green background-color.

P.S. I know how to do all of this by changing html/css, but the question is how to do it only by adding specific jQuery code.

That's the all code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
 <style>
  body {
   font-family: Verdana;
  }
  h3 {
   color: darkblue;
  }
  .rating-circle {
   height: 2em;
   width: 2em;
   border: .1em solid black;
   border-radius: 1.1em;
   display: inline-block;
   margin: 0;
   padding: .1em;
  }

  .rating-hover {
   background-color: yellow !important;
  }

  .rating-chosen {
   background-color: green;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <h3>Rate this</h3>
 <div id="rating-container">
  <div class="rating-circle"></div>
  <div class="rating-circle"></div>
  <div class="rating-circle"></div>
  <div class="rating-circle"></div>
  <div class="rating-circle"></div>
 </div>

 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

 <script>
        $(function() {

          // Frequently used variable:
          var item = $('.rating-circle');

          // Rating-hover effects:
          item.hover(function () {
            $(this).prevAll(item).andSelf().toggleClass('rating-hover');
          });

          // Rating-chosen effects:
          var chosen = item.click(function () {
            chosen.removeClass('rating-chosen');
            $(this).prevAll(item).andSelf().addClass('rating-chosen');
          });

        });
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JYXQap) is the playground in CodePen.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Another more simple solution (only jQuery code with comments):

```
 $(function() {
   var index = -1; // Variable that stores the last index clicked. Default is -1

   /*
    * Add hover event to the circles
    */
   $('.rating-circle').hover(function() {
     // Mouse In
     $('.rating-circle').removeClass('rating-chosen'); // Remove green color from the circles
     $(this).prevAll().addClass('rating-hover'); // Put yellow color to the previous circles
     $(this).addClass('rating-hover'); // Put yellow color to the current circle
   }, function() {
     // Mouse Out
     var clicked = $('.rating-circle').get(index + 1); // Get the element clicked before, using the index var

     $(clicked).prevAll().addClass('rating-chosen'); // Remove green color
     $(this).prevAll().removeClass('rating-hover'); // Remove hover class from the previous circles
     $(this).removeClass('rating-hover'); // Remove hover class from the currrent cicles
   });

   /*
    * Add click event to the circles
    */
   $('.rating-circle').click(function() {
     index = $(this).index(); // Set the new index

     $('.rating-circle').removeClass('rating-chosen');
     $(this).prevUntil().addClass('rating-chosen'); // Add chosen class to previous circles
     $(this).addClass('rating-chosen'); // Add chosen class to the current circle
   });
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Using classes is a good way to work with the display. I wouldn't change that. You could store the selection in a `data-` attribute and handle it that way.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f9ocusxy/

```js
$(function () {

    // Frequently used variable:
    var item = $('.rating-circle');
    var container = $('#rating-container');

    // Rating-hover effects:
    item.hover(function () {
        $(this).prevAll(item).andSelf().toggleClass('rating-hover');
    });

    container.on('mouseout', function () {
        item.each(function () {
            if ($(this).prop('data-chosen') == '1') {
                $(this).addClass('rating-chosen');
            }
        });
    });

    container.on('mouseover', function () {
        item.removeClass('rating-chosen');
    });

    // Rating-chosen effects:
    var chosen = item.click(function () {
        chosen.removeClass('rating-chosen').prop('data-chosen', '0');
        $(this).prevAll(item).andSelf().addClass('rating-chosen').prop('data-chosen', '1');
    });

});
```

```css
  body {
      font-family: Verdana;
  }
  h3 {
      color: darkblue;
  }
  .rating-circle {
      height: 2em;
      width: 2em;
      border: .1em solid black;
      border-radius: 1.1em;
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 0;
      padding: .1em;
  }
  .rating-hover {
      background-color: yellow !important;
  }
  .rating-chosen {
      background-color: green;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Rate this</h3>

<div id="rating-container">
    <div class="rating-circle"></div>
    <div class="rating-circle"></div>
    <div class="rating-circle"></div>
    <div class="rating-circle"></div>
    <div class="rating-circle"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! 
1. Can you please explain what this code do in a few words: `($(this).prop('data-chosen') == '1') `? 
2.And what's better to use: `item.hover(function () {` or `item.on('hover', function () {` and why? Thanks for your time!

Comment: `($(this).prop('data-chosen') == '1')` Checks the value of the `data-chosen` attribute (i.e., is it `1`? Then it was chosen). `.on('hover'` won't work, you'd need to use a `mouse*` event with `.on`. I use `.on` because it's more consistent, and there's little ambiguity. Also, `.on` supports event delegation (required for dynamically added elements).

Answer (score -2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(function() {
          var $circles = $('.rating-circle')

          // mouse over
          $circles.mouseover(function(){
            $circles.removeClass('rating-chosen');
            $(this).addClass('rating-hover');
            $(this).prevAll().addClass('rating-hover');
          });

          // mose leave
          $circles.mouseleave(function(){
            $('.active').prevAll().andSelf().addClass('rating-chosen')
            $(this).removeClass('rating-hover');
            $(this).prevAll().removeClass('rating-hover');
          });

          //mouse clicked
          $circles.click(function(){
            $circles.removeClass('rating-chosen active');
            $(this).addClass('rating-chosen active');
            $(this).prevAll().addClass('rating-chosen');
          });
        });

 </script>
```

Comment: I am sory I cant post the solution to look like a code, But it working.